# Deleting out logs in airflow

Tags: logging, airflow, storage

Hi this is probably a basic question but can I delete out ALL old logs in airflow, not just the ones that are in the scheduler folder?

Just don't want to delete anything out that will mess up airflow.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using these dags for Airflow maintenance, there's also one for log cleanup:
https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags